# Pass html div to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

So I have my server-side code which executes multiple bigquery queries and arranges the results in a table,and this server-side code is called by an ajax call from the client.
I want to be able to send the table/div from my server-side code to client-side and have it render there. Is that possible??

I don't want to be able to create the tables on the client by first getting the JSON results through the call, since I will not know which query will run first and all the results are different. (multiple ajax calls are also out of the question for each query)

**Server code (app.js)**

```
 function printResult(rows, queryNumber) {
    console.log('Query No. '+queryNumber+' Results:____');
    var keys = [];
    if (queryNumber == 1) {
        var table = document.createElement('table');

        var td = [];
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
            var tn1 = document.createTextNode(rows[i].Content_title);
            var tn2 = document.createTextNode(rows[i].Audience_Size);

            td[i] = document.createElement('td');
            td[i].appendChild(tn1);
            td[i + 1] = document.createElement('td').appendChild(tn2);

            tr.appendChild(td[i]);
            tr.appendChild(td[i + 1]);
            table.appendChild(tr);
            res.send(table);
        }
    }
}
```

**Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/example',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {showname: show, counter: uniquesOverallShowsCounter},
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    success: function (data) {




        document.getElementById('outputTables').appendChild(data);


    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: you should also include an example of your data

Comment: This will definitely work, but your `res.send(table)` is currently in the wrong position. place it after your for-loop.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I'm getting an error "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." at the ajax call.

Comment: `appendChild` expects an documentElement (plain JavaScript). As you are already using jQuery, I suggest instead of `document.getElementById('outputTables').appendChild(data);` you should use `$('#outputTables').append(data);` If this is the fix for your problem I'll edit it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but as you pointed out in the comments, there is a problem with the data returned.

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

This is an error which is thrown when you try to append a child node with JavaScript, which is not a documentElement (i.e. `document.createElement('div')`). Since you're already using jQuery, you could easily change your code.

In the success function for the AJAX call, change

```
document.getElementById('outputTables').appendChild(data);
```

to

```
$('#outputTables').append(data);
```

If you want to be able to do multiple AJAX calls from one page and change the table every time (like replace the old table with the new one), you should use `html(data)` instead of `append(data)`.

Comment: Thank you so much helping out!
But i'm getting another error, Error : TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON. 
This is coming from app.js, i think possibly from the res.send() function. Any fixes?

Comment: @HamzaMoiyadi Is that error shown on the client-side or server-side?

Comment: It's coming on the server-side

Comment: @HamzaMoiyadi I'm not sure, but there are a lot of references on StackOverflow for that error. I suggest putting that up in a new question or searching for older questions which could provide an answer, as I'm not that experienced in node.js.

Comment: @HamzaMoiyadi No problem, happy to help! Btw, if this answer fixed your earlier problem, you can always upvote / accept it! Could help others with the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

So can you simply increase one more parameter in your response json based on the query which is hit for example "queryProcessed"?

And add that additional check on client side and render the mark up based on that "queryProcessed"